# How to properly modularize/organize the Javascript for a single page/controller in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I currently have a JS-heavy page with numerous animations, AJAX calls, and responsive features. The entire page is handled by a single angular controller. However, the problem now is my controller is getting very large and I am having trouble navigating through it.

I mainly have 3 types of JS functions inside my controller:
1) Functions that get called immediately, such as fetching objects from factories and calculate the size of certain elements on screen.
2) Functions that get called after page load, such as event handlers for certain elements on the page.
3) Functions exposed to my view (e.g., ng-click functions)

What is the best way of organizing the JS on this page? I want to make my code as readable and modular as possible, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use Service/Factory/Providers for stateless functionality such as http interactions (your ajax calls) and sub controllers for nested functionality.